# Advice For Basic Troubleshooting Long Run Times in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, runtime, ssrs-2008, ssms

I am working on a report in SSRS and have a semi-large sized SQL Server query running on the back-end.

My query has about 10-15 sub-queries and have found some of them to be slowing down my run time to the point that it is unusable for a user (10-15 min run time).

Does anybody have any advice for troubleshooting to find what in my query is slowing down its execution? I'd like to keep it simple (preferably no add-ons), I'm just looking to pin point where the issue is so I can restructure as needed.

I am new to SQL Server, and a medium strength query writer. Any pointers on which functionalities to use would be fantastic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without seeing your query is hard to give any specific advice.  Run the explain plan, find where the query is doing full table scans, add covering index.

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is to execute the same query in SSMS using "Display Estimated Execution Plan" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>). This will parse the query and give you a query plan that you can examine to see where there is a lot of CPU and/or IO being used.

You can also execute the same query in SSMS with the "Actual Execution Plan" enabled. This will execute the query and give you what is actually being run. Usually Estimated and Actual are the same, but not always. Start with Estimated since you don't have to wait for the query to finish.

Look for large table scans and missing indexes. Those are usually the biggest culprits.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said without seeing the query it's difficult to give specific advice but as you mentioned that it has 10-15 sub-queries then this might be part of the problem, especially if these have where clauses.

For example if you have something like

```
SELECT * 
    FROM myTable a
    JOIN (SELECT * FROM AnotherTable WHERE aColumn = @aValue) b
        ON a.SomeColumn = b.SomeColumn
```

This can be slow if the table in the sub-query is large or poorly indexed.

A quick test and potential quick win is to write the subquery results to a temp table and join on that so the same query would look like this...

```
SELECT * INTO #temp FROM AnotherTable  WHERE aColumn = @aValue

SELECT * 
    FROM myTable a
    JOIN #temp b
        ON a.SomeColumn = b.SomeColumn
```